# How to publish ASP.NET Core Web API in .NET 7 to Azure if it expects Startup.cs file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, webapi

I'm trying to publish my ASP.NET Core 7 Web API to Azure but whenever I try to do so I get this error message:

> Publish has encountered an error.
> Be sure that the Startup.cs for your application is calling AddSwaggerGen from within ConfigureServices in order to generate swagger file. Visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=2131205&CLCID=0x409 for more information.
>
> A diagnostic log has been written to the following location:
> "C:\Users\cvale\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4709.tmp"

.NET 7 (and 8) don't have `Startup.cs` and do everything in `Program.cs`. So I have `AddSwaggerGen()` in my `Program.cs`, yet I'm still getting the error when trying to publish.

Has anyone else run into this problem and been able to fix it? Thanks in advance!

I tried placing `builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen()` in `Program.cs`

Comment: According to ChatGPT: The issue seems to be related to how Swashbuckle CLI is being used in conjunction with the new .NET 7 application structure. Adapting the build and deployment process to account for changes in the .NET 7 hosting model or manually handling Swagger file generation might be necessary to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried deploying .NET 7 WEB API to Azure App Service, even I faced the issue.
I have added the below code to my **program.cs** file.

```cs
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(x =>
{
    x.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Web API V1");
if(app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    x.RoutePrefix = "swagger"; // For localhost
else
    x.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
//  For azure
}
);
```

Then, I am able to deploy the App successfully.

**My complete `Program.cs` file**

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(x =>
{
    x.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Web API V1");

if(app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    x.RoutePrefix = "swagger"; 
else
    x.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
}
);

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

**Local output:**

[image]

I deployed my Web API using the Visual Studio Publish option.

[image]

**Successful Deployment**

[image]

Azure Web App **Output**  :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me too in a new project, but my old project still had issues (when generating swagger file)